# Hyperledger Caliper ERROR: Failed to submit transaction using arguments, with error: Error: No discovery results found

Tags: hyperledger, benchmarking, discovery, peer, hyperledger-caliper

I am trying to set up the Hyperledger Caliper for the first time ever to test my Hyperledger Fabric network.

I was following this tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ypF36RGaG1Q, and when I try to run the following command:

`npx caliper launch master --caliper-fabric-gateway-usegateway --caliper-flow-only-test --caliper-fabric-gateway-discovery --caliper-workspace . --caliper-benchconfig benchmarks/scenario/simple/pavan-v2.1/config.yaml --caliper-networkconfig networks/fabric/pavan-v2.1/network-config.yaml`

I got stuck with the following error:

[image]

It happens for all the peers and I have no idea why.

When I use my server to submit transactions, it works fine but using the Hyperledger Caliper it just got errors.

Do you have any idea about how to solve this?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend following the official tutorials that are hosted on the Caliper documentation pages: https://hyperledger.github.io/caliper/v0.4.1/fabric-tutorial/tutorials-fabric-existing/

But more directed towards the issue you are seeing above, is this a local or remote network that you are connecting to?